# Payment method for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios6, paypal, in-app-purchase, payment-gateway

I have an iPhone app like

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/coupons.com/id338380654?mt=8

In my app a user will upload the coupon(it will be a form in which user will fill the coupon information) through the iPhone app and for uploading the coupon he will be charged for some money.

My question is that in this app which feature I can use for payment?

In-App purchase or Paypal like gateway?

As I think it will not be a digital product so in-App purchase can not be used so i have to user Paypal or Zooz like third party for payment.

Please share your advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use Paypal or third party only, because you will sell goods that will not used in iphone.

Explain your services in app metadata when you submit, this can help your app to be approved.